# how to use jquery in angular 16 without npm

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, dom

I am **not using npm** to download jquery, i have the jquery file in *assets/lib/jquery/dist* folder and have the cdn for it in the index.html, i have included the folder in **angular.json**, how do i use it in a component?

index.html

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

angular.json

```
"scripts": [ "src/assets/js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js", ... ]
```

component.ts
`declare var $:any;`

Comment: Best advice: don't use `jquery` with Angular.

Comment: Additional advice: if you are going to use jQuery then use the latest version, not one that's 7 years old

Comment: Why you wanna use `JQuery`? What is your problem? Better let Angular do all about Rendering/Manipulation.

Comment: Addicional advise: If you include in angular.json, **not** include in .html (and viceverse). Angular create a bundle javascript with all the scripts in component plus the .js files includes in .json. Futhermore, **Not** include in assets folder else any folder: if you include in assets folder the only Angular makes is copy the file in "dist/assets"

Comment: @Flo i am using bootstrap 4.3.1, and want to close modal manually as data-dismiss is not working.

Comment: To close a modal in bootstrap 4.3 using jQuery you simply use: `$('#myModal').modal('hide')`

Comment: For this you don't need JQuery. You can use Angular, or use `ng-bootstrap`. It is bootstrap wraped for Angular